# Most atoms have a nonzero magnetic moment, right?

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, quantum-chemistry

This is my feeling.

But more is different. If atoms form a solid, it is hard to say whether the solid will be ferromagnetic or not.

Comment: _it is hard to say whether the solid will be ferromagnetic or not._ Most materials are not ferromagnetic.